# jQuery validator not working in unit testing

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jquery-validate

I have this small HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id='MyForm'>
            <input type='text' required />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>

        <script src="/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
            var validator = $("#MyForm").validate();
            alert(validator.form());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This alerts me with "false", which is the expected behaviour.

The problem comes when I go to unit testing, with js-test-driver:

```
TestCase("MyTests", {

    setUp: function() {
        this.myform = "<form id='MyForm'><input type='text' required /><input type='submit'  /></form>";

        this.validator = $(this.myform).validate();
        jstestdriver.console.log("Does the form validate? " + this.validator.form());
    },

    test_empty: function() {
    },

});
```

This code returns me the string

Does the form validate? true

This is a simplified version of my project of course, but the point is that I dont seem to be able to unit test the validation module im developing, since the jQuery validate plugin doesnt seem to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

As Enrique mentioned, problem is related to jQuery's `:hidden` selector.

Fix:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: "" });
var validator = $("#MyForm").validate();
alert($("#MyForm").valid());
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it! Apparently the plugin bz default ignores ".hidden" inputs. As jQuery doc says,

```
Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.
```

Because unit testing is browser-less, the input elements met this requirements, therefore where ignored by the validation plugin!

=)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) which is the proper way to trigger a test and get a boolean value representing the form's validity.

```
<script>
        var validator = $("#MyForm").validate();
        alert($("#MyForm").valid());
</script>

////

this.validator = $(this.myform).validate();
jstestdriver.console.log("Does the form validate? " + $(this.myform).valid());
```

Comment: `valid()` also gives me `true` in the test and `false` manually